# Wrap the Latin characters sequences up with the span tag

Tags: php, regex

I need the pattern for preg_replace to wrap all sequences of latin characters and digits within the whole HTML page with the tag `<span class="text=arial"></span>`.
For example, the following HTML part

```
<a href="http://domain.com/path" target="_blank">GSPd 役に立つツール： スキル意欲マトリクス</a>
```

should be replaced with:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/path" target="_blank"><span class="text=arial">GSPd</span> 役に立つツール： スキル意欲マトリクス</a>
```

Obviously, only the inner node text should be processed in such way so replacement won't break HTML tags.

What I've tried:

```
$p = '#(?<=\>)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=\<)#ium';
$html = preg_replace(
    $p,
    '><span class="text-arial">$0</span><',
    $html
);
```

This pattern should be extended to include situations when the content consists of mixed characters, e.g. `GSPd 役に立つツール： スキル意欲マトリクス 100`

Comment: I need 1 billion USD, but nobody gives me. :( Now to be constructive: what have you tried besides posting question on SO and how that fails?

Comment: Hi @Leri, I've added what I've tried.

Comment: FYI, added demo and explanation. :)

Comment: Glad the solution helps. :) For the full story I recommend you have a look at [the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-or-replace-a-pattern-except-in-situations-s1-s2-s3-etc/23589204#23589204), or save it for later, I had a lot of fun writing the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match letters and digits while skipping text inside a `<tag>`, you can use the lovely `(*SKIP)(*F)` technique (available in Perl and PCRE) and be done without really breaking a sweat:

```
(?i)<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-z][a-z ]+
```

On the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fS0jW9), look at the Substitution section.

You can pop that into your preg_replace:

```
$regex = "~(?i)<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-z][a-z ]+~";
$replace = '<span class="text=arial">\0</span>';
$replaced = preg_replace($regex,$replace,$original);
```

**How does it work?**

This is a situation where you want to **exclude** some content from being matched—in this case, tags. It is similar to this question about [regex-matching a pattern unless..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `< ... >` tags, then deliberately fails, and the engine skips to the next position in the string. The right side matches "latin text" (which here I have defined as letters and spaces, which can be refined), and we know it is the right text because it was not matched by the expression on the left.

**Further refinements**

You can explore the `[a-z][a-z ]+` and refine it till you are satisfied that it corresponds to your definition of "latin text".

**Reference**

- [Special Backtracking Control Verbs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs)
- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)

Comment: many thanks for the answer - you approach works fine. Just one more question - what is the best way to exclude some tags from matching, such as <style>, <script> etc.?

Comment: `<[^>]*>` already matches  <style>, <script> etc., so do you mean a whole tag, between the opening and closing tag, as in `<b> ... </b>`? In general you just add exclusion rules on the left, it is really simple, please do have a look at the linked SO question as it explains everything, and I am going offline for the night (late here!) :)

Answer (score 1):

I've adjusted zx81's approach a bit to avoid processing text of some tags like style or script:

```
    $regex = "~(?i)<(head|style|script|noscript)[^>]*?>.*?<\/.*?\\1>(*SKIP)(*F)|<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-z0-9&][_a-z0-9&,.;:#%\-/\(\) ]*~smu";        
    $replace = '<span class="text-arial">\0</span>';
    $html = preg_replace($regex,$replace,$html);
```

**What it was needed for**

The client asked to use MS P Gothic for the Japanese characters and Arial for Latin ones. The thing is that the MS P Gothic font already has the Latin glyphs and to apply Arial for Latin characters they should be wrapped with some tag to have an ability for applying `font-family: Arial` via CSS. Adding spans manually is annoying, so many thanks to @zx81 for a good solution!