# PHP Regex (*SKIP)(*F) equal in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How dose i convert below code to javascript regex?

```
$regex = "~(?i)<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-z][a-z ]+~";
$replace = '<span class="text=arial">\0</span>';
$replaced = preg_replace($regex,$replace,$original);
```

[Found her](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118049/wrap-the-latin-characters-sequences-up-with-the-span-tag)

I have tried to follow the [link to the demo](https://regex101.com/r/fS0jW9/1) and use their converter to convert it to JavaScript and now I have this which does not work:

```
/<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-z][a-z ]+/gmi
```

I can not find a substitute for the `(*SKIP)(*F)` part and I´m not that good at regex.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Note: regex101 doesn't convert your regex from one flavor to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tags are properly closed then you may free to use a positive lookahead assertion.

```
([a-z][a-z ]+)(?=[^<>]*<)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fS0jW9/2)

```
> string.replace(/([a-z][a-z ]+)(?=[^<>]*<)/gmi, '<span class="text=arial">$1</span>')
'<a href="http://domain.com/path" target="_blank"><span class="text=arial">GSPd </span>役に立つツール： スキル意欲マトリクス</a>'
```

Comment: Nice. almost works. How do i add characters like:
!"'@#£$%&/{([])}=?+|-

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the exact same behaviour as the regex in PHP, then you can use a function with the replace to do it:

```
var text = '<a href="http://domain.com/path" target="_blank">GSPd 役に立つツール： スキル意欲マトリクス</a>';
text = text.replace(/<[^>]*>|([a-z][a-z ]+)/gi, function (m, s) {
    if (s !== undefined) {
        return '<span class="text=arial">' + s + '</span>';
    } else {
        return m;
    }
});
```

If there is a submatch I have called `s` here, then return it wrapped in span tags, and if not, return the matched part as is.